# Enviar una entidad de grilla por POST

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc

Tengo una vista creada con Razor con la plantilla list en base a un modelo, la vista está bien y muestra en una grilla los datos de la lista, y también tiene sus 3 links (edit datail delete), lo que necesito es que uno de esos links (o bien agregar un cuarto link o botón) me permita capturar el valor del registro (una fila de la grilla que básicamente es un tr del table) entero (de una instancia del modelo) y pasarlo a una acción del controlador por medio de post. Hay N ejemplos de cómo recuperar un dato de la fila de la grilla y pasarla por la URL a una acción de un controlador, yo no quiero pasar datos en la url, y no solo necesito un dato, necesito la fila entera.

O en último caso como puedo pasar el valor de una celda del grid por medio de post y como lo recupero, esto no es exactamente lo que necesito, pero para empezar me puede servir muy bien.

**Nota:** Como analogía pongo el ejemplo de que en webform (ya sé que mvc y webform son totalmente diferentes) puede seleccionar un registro de la grilla y en el evento del select acceder a cada uno de los atributos de la grilla como se fuera una matriz, sin necesidad de pasarla por la url un atributo ni nada por el estilo. Algo parecido quiero poder hacer desde MVC

Comment: Cuántos son los valores que querés enviar?

Comment: Estimado, consulta, después de que tenga los datos en el controlador necesita direccionar a otra vista?, o la acción puede ser asincronica sin enviarlo a otra pagina?. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Yo lo haría de la siguiente forma:

1. En la sección `Scripts` de tu vista escribe una "[**clase**](http://www.phpied.com/3-ways-to-define-a-javascript-class/)" que contenga todos los campos que utilizas y aprovechando Razor, crea un arreglo y llénalo de una vez:

   ```
   @section Scripts
   {
       <script>
           function model(id, valor1, valor2...){
               this.id = id;
               this.valor1 = valor1;
               this.valor2 = valor2;
               ...
           }

           var miArray = [];
           @foreach(var x in Model)
           {
               <text>miArray.push(new model("@x.Id", "@x.Valor1", "@x.Valor2"...);</text>
           }
       </script>
   }
   ```

---

2. También en el script, crea una función que reciba como parámetro algún identificador del renglón y haz la llamada Ajax desde ahí:

   ```
   function sendRow(id){
       //Encuentra un "x" tal que el id de ese "x" sea igual al id del parámetro.
       let renglonPorEnviar = miArray.find(x => x.id == id);
       $.ajax({
           url: "tu/url",
           data: renglonPorEnviar,
           type: "POST",
           dataType: "Json",  //Si aplica
           success: function(data){ ... }
       });
   }
   ```

   (Aquí hago uso de la función [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/find) de JS para seleccionar el elemento).

(También defino la variable como [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/let) en lugar de `var` para un alcance local solamente).

---

3. Agrega un botón a tu renglón de la tabla que tenga vinculada la función del paso 2:

   ```
   <button onclick="sendRow('@Model...ID')">Enviar</button>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Te paso un ejemplo que usé hace unos años. Era una grilla con muchas filas. En cada una tenía 2 opciones y con  `actionlink` enviaba varios valores al controlador.

**BES** era un objeto dentro de una colección (La grilla era una colección de objetos BES) y enviaba los atributos que necesita del objeto en la fila elegida.

Espero que el ejemplo te sirva para darte una idea de cómo hacer.

**La vista:**

```
<td>
 @Html.ActionLink("Ver/Editar", "VerEditar", "BombaElectroSumergible", new { IDBombaElectroSumergible = BES.IDBombaElectroSumergible, IDPozo = Model.IDPozo, FechaFinFuncionamiento = BES.FechaFinFuncionamiento, FechaInicioFuncionamiento = BES.FechaInicioFuncionamiento }, null)
                @if (@Roles.IsUserInRole(@HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name, "Administrador"))
                {
                    @Html.ActionLink("| Borrar", "Delete", "BombaElectroSumergible", new { IDBombaElectroSumergible = BES.IDBombaElectroSumergible, IDPozo = Model.IDPozo }, new { onclick = "return confirm('Borrar BES?');" })} </td>
```

**El controlador:**

```
public ActionResult VerEditar(int IDBombaElectroSumergible, int IDPozo, DateTime FechaFinFuncionamiento, DateTime FechaInicioFuncionamiento)
    {
```

Comment: Si me parece bueno el ejemplo, una duda, estos datos son enviados por la URL verdad? porque lo que necesito es que los datos no pasen por la URL.

Comment: Sí. Van por la url. En general MVC funciona así. Para que eso no pase, deberías hacer un Post del formulario, pero no es lo que vos necesitás hacer no?

Comment: SI eso lo tengo claro, en realidad es como prácticamente ahora lo tengo funcionando, pasando los datos por la url, pero para un caso particular necesito que no pase por la URL, que se envíen por POST, mas que todo es el motivo de mi pregunta.

Comment: Claro, pero no podés mandar el formulario completo. Solo queres mandar una fila.

Comment: Y crees que exista una manera truco framework o lo que sea que me permita hacer eso?

Comment: Para eso deberías armar un formulario solo con esos valores y hacer el post. Por ejemplo, una ventana de detalles y de ahi el post. Ese formulario tendria como modelo un objeto de la lista y el controlador esperaria ese objeto como parametro ¿se entiende?

Comment: pero al formulario de detalles tendría que pasarle el dato por la url, en lo cual seguiría teniendo el problema, que complicado, necesito que del link salgan los datos a una acción por post pero me parece que se esta complicando mucho, y crees que en el foreach que va poniendo cada tr, si le pongo un form (como un form por tr) funcionaria???

Comment: Pero en el detail no pasas todo el objeto. Solo el id.

Comment: Intentare lo que dices, aunque en cada grilla del sistema tendria que aumentar una vista extra lo cual me parece un poco tedioso, itentare poner cada <tr> dentro de un form asi tal vez pueda conseguir enviar todo el registro por medio de POST.

Comment: Lo de la vista extra capaz no es necesario. Podrías usar la vista que ya tenés, la de detalle (mandando solo el id). Y de ahí reenviar el formulario por Post al controlador.